# Vue 3 single Collapse

Tags: onclick, vuejs3, toggle, expand

Here my component that I work for. when I clicked on one of collapse button it will show both of it. please help me to find the solution that allow me to click on on the collapse component and only one that I clicked working for other is close.

```
const isShow = ref(false);
```

```
<script setup>
import { ArrowDownBold } from "@element-plus/icons-vue";
import { ArrowUpBold } from "@element-plus/icons-vue";

import { ref } from "vue";

const isShow = ref(false);
</script>
<template>
  <div class="py-4">
    <div class="relative flex flex-col justify-between w-full h-full bg-white">
      <div class="z-2 flex items-center bottom-[-200px] justify-center">
        <div
          @click="isShow = !isShow"
          class="flex justify-center bg-gray-200 py-1 px-2 text-sm z-50 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer space-x-2"
        >
          <p>VIEW DETAIL</p>
          <ArrowUpBold
            v-if="isShow"
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="w-4"
            color="rgba(75 85 99)"
          />
          <ArrowDownBold
            v-else
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="w-4"
            color="rgba(156 163 175)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <Transition name="collapse1">
          <div
            class="w-full overflow-hidden h-auto top-[12px] bg-gray-200"
            v-if="isShow"
          >
            <h1>Collapse 1</h1>
          </div>
        </Transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="py-4">
    <div class="relative flex flex-col justify-between w-full h-full bg-white">
      <div class="z-2 flex items-center bottom-[-200px] justify-center">
        <div
          @click="isShow = !isShow"
          class="flex justify-center bg-gray-200 py-1 px-2 text-sm z-50 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer space-x-2"
        >
          <p>VIEW DETAIL</p>
          <ArrowUpBold
            v-if="isShow"
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="w-4"
            color="rgba(75 85 99)"
          />
          <ArrowDownBold
            v-else
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="w-4"
            color="rgba(156 163 175)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <Transition name="collapse1">
          <div
            class="w-full overflow-hidden h-auto top-[12px] bg-gray-200"
            v-if="isShow"
          >
            <h1>Collapse 2</h1>
          </div>
        </Transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi sir! can you guild if I have a lot of collapse component. so I need to click it by open the one that I was click as it ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a shared variable for the both collapsible sections so they are collapsed/expanded together. You could make the variable an object and use its props as an expanded flag.

But in your case you should create a component for the collapsible detail sections:

```
<script setup>
import { ArrowDownBold } from "@element-plus/icons-vue";
import { ArrowUpBold } from "@element-plus/icons-vue";
import { CollapsibleDetails } from './CollapsibleDetails.vue';

</script>
<template>
  <CollapsibleDetails><h1>Collapse 1</h1></CollapsibleDetails>
  <CollapsibleDetails><h1>Collapse 2</h1></CollapsibleDetails>
</template>
```

CollapsibleDetails.vue:

```
<script setup>

import {ref} from 'vue';

const isShow = ref(false);

</script>
<template>
  <div class="py-4">
    <div class="relative flex flex-col justify-between w-full h-full bg-white">
      <div class="z-2 flex items-center bottom-[-200px] justify-center">
        <div
          @click="isShow = !isShow"
          class="flex justify-center bg-gray-200 py-1 px-2 text-sm z-50 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer space-x-2"
        >
          <p>VIEW DETAIL</p>
          <ArrowUpBold
            v-if="isShow"
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="w-4"
            color="rgba(75 85 99)"
          />
          <ArrowDownBold
            v-else
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="w-4"
            color="rgba(156 163 175)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <Transition name="collapse1">
          <div
            class="w-full overflow-hidden h-auto top-[12px] bg-gray-200"
            v-if="isShow"
          >
            <slot></slot>
          </div>
        </Transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi sir! can you guild if I have a lot of collapse component. so I need to click it by open the one that I was click as it ID.

Comment: @DinSomnang do you want to have an array of collapsible content items with IDs and collapse/expand programmatically based on an item's ID? it's possible. BUT. since my answer correct I would ask you to accept it (the checkbox) so I'll be rewarded with 15 points and will be motivated elaborate further, thanks. That's how stackoverflow works - good answers should be rewarded